# How to understand event timeline in spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Im trying to investigate performance problem in our Spark Application. Each of my executors is configured to have 5 cores. Here is what I saw in a stage details on event timeline:

[image]

The question is one does one of the green rectangles is lower/higher than another one? What does it mean?

Judging by the event timeline... Even in spite of each executors have 5 cores, most of the time the only one task is ran in parallel. My spark properties:

```
spark.driver.memory 4g
spark.executor.instances 48
spark.executor.cores 5
```

Comment: It looks like you have two cores defined per executor. It looks like most of the time *two* tasks run in parallel. I suggest that you [edit] the question and include the actual relevant settings, from the "Environment" tab in the spark history server.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Added some properties. No, actually I have 5 cores on each executor

Comment: @RealSkeptic Can u suggest where to look at? Maybe there are some DAG-scheduler issue.\

Comment: Assuming you are running on Yarn, you should also look at the vcores used, vcores total and at memory settings in the yarn page when you run the application.